# Start Laravel 5.3 app from different domain?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I know it's possible to load up a Laravel app from inside of another framework by doing something like this...

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../laravel-site/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../laravel-site/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
$response = $kernel->handle( $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
```

...but is there any way to do that where you can say "And start from the index"?

I'm wondering because I managed to boot up my Laravel app from a Wordpress installation, but everything really only works well on the homepage "/" since that's also a URL in the Laravel app. Once I go to a page on the Wordpress site that doesn't match up with a Laravel url, nothing wants to work because **$response** is just the 404 page. Can't authenticate users or anything.

I can manually fix it by adding every Wordpress url I want to use Laravel functions on into the **routes/web.php** file, but that's not clean.

I'm thinking I need to figure out how to say... make the Laravel app and act like you're on the main page, not some random uri picked up from Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the question about what is handling auth, but you could treat the Laravel app as the primary app, with a "catch all" fallback to Wordpress - untested, but something like:

```
// Registration Routes...
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    // foo 2
});

Route::get('{any}', function() {
    require_once(/* wordpress index path */; 
})->where('any', '.*');
```

404's and whatnot would obviously need to be handled in Wordpress though.

If you need Laravel and WP to talk, this library is great: https://github.com/corcel/corcel

Comment: Looks really interesting! I'll have to give that a shot first thing tomorrow. As for Corcel, I know it says it's for using WordPress as the back end/admin panel. Have you ever used it with the intention of a Laravel back end/admin panel and a WordPress frontend?

Comment: It's an interesting question - make sure to check back and let people know how you go, because I'm sure others will search for the same in the future

Comment: I ended up going with the wildcard and letting WP handle all the 404's, since the Laravel backend is not publicly accessible anyways. Works great! Can now use Laravel functions and calls all across the Wordpress site. I'll check out Corcel in a few weeks when I'm not so crunched for time!

Comment: Nice! Good luck